# Criação de Entidades com Migração (JPA / FlyWay) - Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory

Tags: java, jpa, flyway

Boa noite! Estou tendo dificuldade em realizar o relacionamento das entidades e recebendo o seguinte erro abaixo. Já tentei usar outros relacionamentos, mas sem sucesso. O usuário pode ter vários tickets / Um ticket tem somente um user e um assignedUser e pode ter vários changes / São vários changeStatus para um ticket e para um user

Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Column(s) not allowed on a @ManyToOne property: com.projeto.api.entites.Ticket.assignedUser

@Entity
@Table(schema = "projeto_api", name = "user", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"name_user", "email"})})
public class User {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name_user")
@NotBlank
private String nameUser;

@Email
@NotBlank
private String email;

@Size(min = 6)
@NotBlank
private String password;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_ticket", foreignKey = @ForeignKey (name = "user_ticket_fk"))
private List<Ticket> tickets;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ProfileEnum profile;
```

}

@Entity
@Table(schema = "projeto_api", name = "ticket", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"number"}))
public class Ticket {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "date_ticket")
private Date dateTicket;

private String title;

private Long number;

private String description;

private String image;

//Usuário que gerou o ticket
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_user", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "ticket_user_fk"))
private User user;

//Usuário atribuído pelo Técnico
@ManyToOne
@Column(name = "assigned_user")
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_assigned_user", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "ticket_assigned_user_fk"))
private User assignedUser;

@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_change_status", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "ticket_change_status_fk"))
private List<ChangeStatus> changes;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private StatusEnum status;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private PriorityEnum priority;
```

}

@Entity
@Table(schema = "projeto_api", name = "change_status")
public class ChangeStatus {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_ticket", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "change_status_ticket_fk"))
private Ticket ticket;

@ManyToOne
@Column(name = "user_change")
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_user_change", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "change_status_user_change_fk"))
private User userChange;

@Column(name = "date_change_status")
private Date dateChangeStatus;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private StatusEnum status;
```

}

Comment: Quando se utiliza `@ManyToOne` não se pode declarar `@Column`, remova onde houver estas duas anotações no mesmo campo, deixando apenas `@ManyToOne` configurando com `@JoinColumn`

Comment: Obrigada @nullptr funcionou. Estou iniciando com Java e demais tecnologias relacionadas. Tenho muito a aprender. rs